# Handling variables and functions declared on external js file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have several PHP files, each of them is a webpage in HTML (as well as PHP functions).
Besides, I need to define the same JavaScript variables and functions in every of those PHP files.
I would like to avoid duplicating those variables and functions definitions for cleanup.
For instance, my files are the following: file1.php, variables.js, functions.js

If I need to execute functions with no dependencies from the file1 or variables file, I can execute:

```
//This sentence executes function1() from func.js file
$.getScript('includes/func.js', function(){ function1()});
```

However, I want to load some variables defined on variables.js, and call those variables from either file1.php and functions.js. How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Based on the Strikeskids quick responses:
Is there any way to define a set of variables and functions **only once**, and use them from several HTML files like if they were all defined on each of those HTML files?

Comment: You can't call javascript functions in php

Comment: I can if they're not bounded by <? ?> tags. For my question, it is not relevant those files are in .php or .html format, I believe.

Comment: You can't get the results from a js file in your php script unless you run node on the server or use ajax to send them back.

Comment: You alter your approach to the problem. That's how. This whole js / php mixing is horrible, and dependency on global variable state as well. How about you **supply** your javascript code / functions with appropriate variables / objects instead of your functions accessing those variables globally?

Comment: @user2957378 You are mixing up some different things. Outsinde <? ?> tags isn't PHP. Dependent on server configuration you could do system calls to start a javascript interpreter from PHP, e.g. node-js. When you write code outside <?...?> it is only simple text sent to the browser. The client side useragent then decides how this is interpreted.

Comment: why you do not just insert a <script type="text/javscript" src="yourVariableDeclarations.js"></script> at the beginning of every php file you want it in? Or I am getting your purpose not right?

Comment: Ok, so my next approach will be to declare a Javascript object containing all variables and functions and simply store that object into a variable in file.php/file.html

Comment: Dynamic generated JavaScript might be useful in some kind of artificial intelligence project. In common use case it isn't a good approach. Why not simply include JavaScript statically from HTML? For special purposes you could generate the one or other function call if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include `<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>` in every HTML page, preferably at the end of body for site load performance. `type="text/javascript"` attribute can be omitted since mimetype is selected by the server response header. This will also cache the static JavaScript library to minimize network traffic.

If you want to provide a customizable download of a library similar to jQuery-UI, have a look at [file-get-contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)